# Unlock phone with a different button

Tags: lock-screens, nexus-4

I have a Nexus 4, and everything is OK, but I have realised that the power button is not working as well as I want. Sometimes I have to press it twice or push harder, so my question is: could I set up my phone to unlock with a different button, for example with the volume buttons? Is there any solution in case that the power button becomes inoperable?

Comment: It *might* be possible using *Tasker*, if your device has a *camera* button (which was, when I looked last, the only hardware button you could bind actions to)...

Comment: If your device doesn't have a hardware camera button, as @Izzy suggests, then I believe it's also possible on a rooted device. But you'd essentially lose a button for the sake of the new power button.

Comment: But I just have 3 buttons, power, and two volume buttons :s

Comment: I don't think you would sacrifice one of your volume buttons. And the power button is just the one you want to "replace". So the answer is somehow obvious, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the power and back button failed in my rooted LG P500, I used [Button savior](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smart.swkey&hl=en).  This app works without any restriction on rooted devices and with few limitations on unrooted.

This app creates a small overlay on the screen (which is customisable in terms of its size, visibility, position etc.) and pressing this overlay slides a virtual buttons on screen to lock, volume up and down, back, home, search, menu, camera etc.

It was indeed aptly named for as it saved my trip to service centre to shell out money on my phone to replace the keys.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will keep this answer in mind. Definitely I will use it!

Comment: The power button is not actually replaceable with any soft key as it is also used for powering up, during which no software component can help. Other than that this key plays important role in booting to recovery mode. Again this will not work with software key. But in my case the power button was only working inconsistently as you said and the back button totally stopped working. Had a difficult time when using CWM and hence switched over TWRP touch recovery.

Answer (score 4):

A week ago or so I started using [Gravity Screen Off](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.plexnor.gravityscreenofffree).

Answer (score 0):

Same problem occurred to my fathers Nexus 4 phone. We tried 3-4 soft best of them is **Auto Screen On** this soft used Proximity sensor on Left top just tap that sensor once or twice (set in setting).. and go your phone will unlock w/o power btn. actually it also support gravity sensor but may be not compatible with nexus 4.

Also works w/o rooting  ..

Comment: So, Did any of those Apps work fine?