# What to do if my samsung tab keeps on resetting itself?

Tags: tablet, shutdown

My Samsung Tab keeps on resetting itself upon powering on, it goes to home screen and after a while (about 10 seconds) restarts itself. This keeps on and on until i shutdown the Tab.

My Tablet has been drained of battery charge due to excessive playing of games of my nephews. So I Charged my Tablet for a while and left to get something in the kitchen. I Didn't see that one of my nephews immediately turned it on upon Minutes after I plugged it on the charger and this is what happened next, my other nephew accidentally unplugged the charger of my tablet. I saw what happened as I was returning in the living room. I heard 3 beeps and the tablet shut itself down immediately after.

I tried to charge it again and tried to open and this is what happened it keeps on restarting and restarting. I have not taken my tablet to a technician yet. What should I do?

Comment: 3 beeps? Sounds like the battery has carked it(I.e. It may be a battery probelm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We also had this problem with our Samsung Tablet. Leaving it charging for over 48 hours untouched seemed to make it stop restarting.

Try leaving the device charging for a long time and see what happens. Eventually the device should have enough charge to prevent it from restarting.

Answer (score 0):

It might be some hardware issue
try changing the hardware buttons to software buttons or interchanging the buttons for power and volume

[this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46578/unlock-phone-with-a-different-button) might help

Comment: I want to try your suggestion but unfortunately i cannot install any apps due to my tablet keeps on resetting itself once I turned it on

Comment: if you have a good internet connection
just log into your google account on you computer then go to the play store and install the app from there
then when your tab restarts it would automatically be downloaded

Answer (score 0):

- Did you rooted your tab,If not try clear cache on recovery menu?
- To go to recovery menu while powering on press and Hold POWER + VOLUME up BUTTON, when the Samsung icon comes up leave the buttons.
- If this method not working, Try below method
- Root your tab then clear/wipe dalvik cache on Recovery menu.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue i have, but after read a lot of forum this problem because of battery, just plug in to charger and its back to normal. after that i turn off the tab and keep charging for long hours. I also notice this happen because i use Samsung s7 edge fast charger to charge my tab. the battery become not stable. So do not ever use fast charger for your tab it will ruin your tab battery