# My Nexus 6 turns itself off randomly; How can I fix this?

Tags: calls, crashes, shutdown, nexus-6

TL;DR: Nexus 6 shuts itself off randomly, seems to be connected to the camera, wifi, and cellular. Internet is full of placebo solutions and "me-too" posts. Logcat output below.

---

I've been having this problem for months now, but it wasn't there when the phone was new. Here's what happens.

- I will be on a phone call, using a headset, and when I open the camera app, WhatsApp, or - sometimes - when I'm doing nothing at all, the phone will just shut itself off instantly.
- Sometimes it'll shut itself off when I leave the house and look for a Car on DriveNow. My house has Edge coverage, my street has LTE.
- A few times the phone would shut off again after I've switched it back on. This can happen a few times in a row. Waiting before I do anything after switching it back on *seems* to help.

Note:

- **I am *nearly* always on a phone call when this happens.**
- I think the display is **always** on when it turns itself off.

Searching the internet, I have found tons and tons of complains of the same or similar problems, and I've been reading the Google product forums, with hundreds of me-too type posts and placebo solutions.

People will claim that uninstalling an app I and the other posters have never heard of fixed the problem for them. Some claim what wiping the phone will help, others say that that doesn't work.

The problem occurs very sporadically. It's very hard to find out whether doing anything has fixed it or not.

This is what I've tried so far:

- I've uninstalled all apps I can live without. Making sure I only use apps that I have been using when the thing was working properly.
- I've deleted the cache partition (one of these placebo solutions)

I would try a factory reset, but the data inside of WhatsApp is extremely important to me and I don't have a spare phone to load my WhatsApp backup before wiping the Nexus 6 (you need your SIM for WhatsApp to work, so the emulator doesn't help me). I don't want to bring the phone back to the store or send it to Motorola for the same reason. If I can help it at all.

For the last two days, I've been keeping my phone connected to my computer with a shell open and watching the output of `logcat`, and a few minutes ago it did indeed shut itself of with the shell connected. Here's [**the logcat output from shortly before the crash**](http://pastebin.com/u0dRqvAT)

I wouldn't be posting this Question, I'd just live with it until I get a spare phone and send the Nexus 6 in for repair, except for the fact that I now have the output from logcat, and that might make sense to someone here.

- The phone is running Android 5.1.1 (<s>LMY47Z</s> LMY48I)
- I have a german T-Mobile SIM
- Here's a [list of apps I have installed](https://www.notehub.org/2015/8/11/audiblehttpsplaygooglecomstoreappsdetail)

#### Update

I did a factory reset. It went fine. :) Of course I have no idea whether that fixed it or not.

#### Update the second

It didn't :-(

The problem also happens (just happened) in safe mode.

#### Update the third

It also happens on the Android M developer preview. I've since bought a Moto E (lovely) and I will send the Nexus 6 in for repair. Hoping I won't get it back with a message saying there's no fault.

Comment: I suspect the device is not rooted. Is it so? Considering a non-rooted device, have you looked at [How do I use Google Drive backup?](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000019) and [How do I save my chat history?](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/23756533) -- both from FAQ at WhatsApp's website. // By "*I don't have a spare phone to load my WhatsApp backup before wiping the Nexus 6*' -- do you intend to mean that you want to verify if the backup is good or not if you've had a spare phone (since emulator doesn't work here)?

Comment: Not rooted. Yes that's exactly what I meant. The Google Drive backup sounds more promising than what I've read (backing up to your devices sd card, which the n6 doesn't have obviously).

Comment: Looking at logcat, don't do anything drastic.

Comment: might be a hardware problem<br>
try <a href="http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/117353/what-to-do-if-my-samsung-tab-keeps-on-resetting-itself/117355?noredirect=1#comment146433_117355">this</a>

Comment: It's not the physical button I don't think. If the phone turned itself off because the  sleep/wake button is shorted, I'd notice the vibration and the popup that appears when you hold it down.

Comment: My Nexus 6 had this problem before, but after updating to the newest Android OS it seems to not have happened again for a very long time.

Comment: Okay so i guess what's done on the bounty is done, but i would like to see your logcat, if your device repeats the issue after you get it back.

Answer (score 6):

This is a partial answer based on the output of logs provided.

Okay, after looking at the logcat, my guess would be a buffer overrun error originating/stemming from mm-camera and connected services/processes and ion memory allocation.

Snippets,

```
08-11 17:51:19.504 E/libaprpmem( 1539):  Ion allocation success virtaddr : ret=2996989952 fd=48 heapid=33554432
08-11 17:51:19.507 E/libaprpmem( 1539):

08-11 17:51:19.332 E/mm-camera( 1539): mct_stream_destroy_buffers: Exit

08-11 17:51:19.337 E/mm-camera-isp2( 1539): isp_port_check_caps_unreserve:807 ide 3000f port 0xb6749d60
08-11 17:51:19.337 E/mm-camera-isp2( 1539): isp_handler_destroy_stream_param:1616 num_streams 0
```

Okay so don't be ready to quote me on that but dig this article discussing buffer underrun/overrun http://www.articlesfactory.com/articles/computers/buffer-underrun-and-overrun-scenarios.html

I can't pin it to a specific specific cause but try setting your camera resolution to as low a setting that you can get it, and if you can, disable your proximity sensor. Either when the camera crashes it takes your phone with it or even though it crashes , seemingly repeatedly, it keeps gobbling up your ram till your phone tanks and shuts off. Hit some development sites and see what devs have to say or are doing with respect to this subject if it's common. It could be "fixed" by a decent/corrected kernel build. Unless you are under contract or tied down by the knox/enterprise-ability thing.

You may need to go pirate/commando and break your contract to save your data though. Meaning rooting and ripping all your data off the device.

OH! and i forgot this,

```
08-11 17:49:33.932 W/ResourcesManager(29010): Asset path '/system/framework/com.google.android.media.effects.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
```

That one is a genuine WTF.run `ls -al /system/framework/` and look for zero length *.jar files.

More- missing lib

```
08-11 17:51:10.373 E/mm-camera( 1539): Tuning lib open failed: dlopen failed: library "libmmcamera_tuning.so" not found
```

Edit- Rerun your logcat "live" as `logcat |grep F/` as before with phone connected till crash.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an adb backup or use Titanium Backup to back up your Whatsapp data. Then you should do a factory reset, if that does not help, you should reflash the original firmware.

Comment: WhatsApp doesn't allow backup from ADB and we're yet to confirm whether OP's device is rooted. Besides, what merit lies in re-flashing firmware? Consider explaining the reasoning behind it.

Comment: This is what I'm getting at. Adb backup sound wonderful, but if that skips some of these files, which it sound like it might, that'd be so annoying. This is why I would like to test restoring my backup to another device.

Comment: I see no evidence why flashing the device would solve my problem. The system image would be identical (it's read-only), and everything else would be restored from a backup, surely? Happy to try it though if I can figure out how to back up my stuff.

Comment: @StefanoPalazzo Here: [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28296) is the way to backup non-rooted devices before flashing. Note that it has limitations and as said, WhatsApp wouldn't be backed up by ADB.

Comment: There is a tool over on XDA that might help you. http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2770982 But on the ADB issue. One thing you can try to do is to pull the data instead of using backup. Then once you factory reset the device. You can reinstall the app then use ADB to push the database back on to the device. In theory... I know devs can set the allow_backup flag to no, but that shouldn't stop you from pulling the data instead. **Edit** Also, Not sure if you tried this. But this is from the whatsapp website. https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/20902622

Comment: @StefanoPalazzo Also on the whole flashing thing. From time to time there are bits of old code that get left behind and can cause problems. That's why most of the time when you have problems people suggest a flashing factory images and sometimes a factory reset will suffice. I know you said its been happening for a few months now. Did it start after you took an OTA?

Answer (score 0):

1. Backup data
2. Flash Original file or another ROM , this will definitely solve your problem.
3. Enjoy.

Comment: Flashing the factory image didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Install a different ROM , if that doesn't solve your problem , then Power IC or battery may be the problem.